# Random text to fade

Tags: text, random, ios6, fading

How do I get random text to fade, from `text1` to `text2`?

My code is as follows:

```
 -(IBAction)generateNumbers; {
    int randomNumber = arc4random() % 1;
    switch (randomNumber) {
        case 0:
            label.text = @"text1";
            break;
        case 1:
            label.text = @"text2";
            break;
        default:
            break;
     }
}
```

Comment: change this one int randomNumber = arc4random() % 2;

Comment: If you have 10 numbers you want 1 to 10, `use arc4random()%10+1`. If you have array then use `arc4random()%array.count`

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction)generateNumbers; {
int randomNumber = arc4random() % 2;
switch (randomNumber) {
case 0:
    label.text = @"text1";
    break;
case 1:
    label.text = @"text2";
    break;
default:
    break;
 }
}
```

For fadeIn/Out use this methods

```
- (void) setTextWithFade {
   [label setAlpha:1];
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
   [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
   [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(fadeDidStop)];
   [lbl setAlpha:0];
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)fadeDidStop {
   label.text = @"new text";
   [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
   [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
   [lbl setAlpha:1];
   [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

call the first method when you are click the button like this:

```
 [self setTextWithFade];
```

Comment: but how do I get a text to fade. so every time I press a button the text will fade into a new text